# angularjs firebase authentication cookies are persistent into the next user session

Tags: angularjs, cookies, firebase, session-cookies, firebase-authentication

The problem is when a user 1 has signed out, and once the user 2 signs in, either the info of the user 2 is not show, or the info of user 1 is still shown. Apparently the cookies from the first user still hang around and prevent the transition softly.
here is my signout controller, does anyone have any improvements on this?

```
app.controller("MysignOutCtrl", ["$scope",function ($scope) {
    $scope.signOut = function () {
        firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
            console.log("Sign-out successful");
        }, function(error) {
            toastr.error(error.message, error.reason, { timeOut: 10000 });
        })
    };
}]);
```

Comment: As commented below, you can only have one user logged in. It is not clear what you are doing. It is better to stick to the API instead of trying to manipulate the underlying web storage mechanism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add the `localStorage.clear();` after signout.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use [AngularFire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire), always use its wrapper methods to prevent some unexpected behaviors. 
   I would use `$firebaseAuth().$signOut()` method.
2. Firebase does not support multiple logged in users. If you loggin with second account, it overwrites existing user data.

Comment: should I add then localStorage.clear if I use the angularfire?